# Play Camera Anim - Unreal Blueprints

Tags: camera

I'm very new to unreal and was hoping some one could help me with this problem. I have 2 buttons which appear on the side of the screen (on the left of the attached graphic).

When you click on the first button the camera changes and moves. Once that animation ends it goes back to the original player controller.

Is there a way of getting the new camera to hold on the last frame so it can remain until the second button is clicked which stops the new camera movement.

thank you,
Matt

[Screengrab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhXMK.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to fix this.
Spawn/Create a new camera at the exact location and rotation where you first camera animation ends. Then use 'set view with blend' on the new camera.
At that moment you can do whatever you want :)